# Intra-group calculations on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form of:

```
code        date        count
AA          201205      1
AA          201309      2
AA          201310      12
AA          201410      7
BB          201305      3
BB          201309      1
CC          201404      5
```

The date is in the form of yyyymm.

I want to group the data by the values in the 'code' column and sum the values in the count for each code value for the last 6 months and for all time before that. So the new dataframe would look like:

```
code        last 6 months       before that
AA          7                   15
BB          0                   4
CC          5                   0
```

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe:

```
>>> gr = df.groupby(['code', df['date'] > 201403])
>>> pv = gr['count'].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
>>> namer = {True:'last 6 months', False:'before that'}.get 
>>> pv.columns = list(map(namer, pv.columns))
>>> pv
      before that  last 6 months
code                            
AA             15              7
BB              4              0
CC              0              5
```